# Weird output in Python program

Tags: python

I tried to make a program to determine whether a number is odd or not, I get the following output

```
def is_odd(n):
    if n % 2 != 0:
       print(True)
    else:
       print(False)
```

if I put

```
print(is_odd(1))
```

I get:

```
True
None
```

Whatever number I choose, I  always get

```
None
```

at the end.

Comment: You missed `return` statement

Comment: You are printing inside the function, but you are also printing the *result* of the function which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return something to remove this None . You can also modify the code by returning the True or false and print it in the main